# How to draw/plot a rectangle or box on the chart

Tags: plot, colors, rectangles, box, pine-script

I couldn't find any plot shape in pine to draw rectangles... maybe I missed something?

I'm drawing several lines on the chart, between exact specified coordinates:

```
upper_hline = line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, extend=extend.none, color=color.green)
lower_hline = line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2, extend=extend.none, color=color.red)
```

Is there any possibility to color the space between that lines?

I tried using the "fill" function, but it doesn't work with line objects:

```
fill(upper_hline, lower_hline, color=color.blue, transp=70)
```

I also tried "label.new" with "label.style_square", but that doesn't work as well, because you can't set its exact position, size and transparency.

Any solution yet?

Comment: There's no way to plot filled shape in this way. The only possible rectangle here is the `plotshape` function, but I suppose it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that doesn't do it. So maybe there will be a solution in a next pine version.